# Oracle Execute Immediate SELECT error

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USP_table_row_count
AS
    v_id  NUMBER :=0;
    v_table_name VARCHAR2(100);
    v_owner VARCHAR2(100);
    v_count NUMBER;
    v_row_count NUMBER;

    CURSOR c_tables IS 
        SELECT fld_id ,fld_owner, fld_table_name,fld_row_count_new FROM tbl_table_row_count;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_tables;
    LOOP
        FETCH c_tables INTO v_id,v_owner, v_table_name, v_row_count;
        EXIT WHEN c_tables%notfound;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '||v_owner||'.'||v_table_name INTO v_count;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_owner || ' '|| v_table_name ||' '|| v_count);

        UPDATE TBL_TABLE_ROW_COUNT SET FLD_ROW_COUNT_OLD=V_ROW_COUNT WHERE FLD_id=v_id;
        UPDATE TBL_TABLE_ROW_COUNT SET FLD_ROW_COUNT_NEW=V_COUNT WHERE FLD_id=v_id;
        UPDATE TBL_TABLE_ROW_COUNT SET FLD_row_DIF=V_COUNT-v_ROW_COUNT WHERE FLD_id=v_id;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE c_tables;
END;
/
```

So I have the procedure above. I have a table where I have all the table from all schemas in DB. In this procedure I'm trying to insert into the table every table rows count. The problem is I get this error:**00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"**. The odd thing is that the DBMS_OUPUT outputs perfect the data for every table. If I make an exception and try to execute immediate only for the user I'm not logged into it works.

Comment: Why do you need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` for a `SELECT` statement?

Comment: @user75ponic - because they want to pass the table owner and table name as  variables.

Comment: If you move the `dbms_output` before the `execute immediate` you'll see what it attempted. btw a [Cursor FOR loop](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm) would simplify this a bit.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_execute_immediate.htm), perhaps it would be useful.

Comment: @raulnoob -  Dynamic SQL is the devil to work with. You need better exception handling. A good start would be to display the dynamic statement **before you execute it** . That way you'll be able to spot your bloomer when it fails. Most likely it's a problem with the data in `tbl_table_row_count`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - one UPDATE statement instead of three would simplify it further :)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson that helped me, it was a system table which had no count or something like that. TY